# Jenkins slave (linux) is taking Windows slash in maven path

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'am configuring Jfrog Artifactory with Jenkins through pipeline.

It is master-slave architecture.

Jenkins master is on Windows where slave is on Redhat Linux.

For maven configuration i have specified on global tools configuration like this: `/opt/tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9`

As i have specified in master(Windows) and it wont be able to find in slave (Linux) i have configured in slave also, under tools option.

I have specified exact locaion of maven: `/opt/tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9`

When i'm trigging build and Artifactory connection is being established but after that build goes failure with the error message:

```
java.nio.fs.InvalidPathException illegal char <*> at Index 41 /opt/tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\*
```

After apache-maven-3.3.9 it is adding Windows slash, which is causing this error.

Anyone can tell me how to resolve this error?

This would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you define two maven tools - one for windows and one for unix, and then using an "if" statement in your pipeline script, choose the right one, depending on the Jenkins agent OS?

Comment: let me see. in artifactory pipeline i'm specifying linux maven name under rt.maven tool = 'name of linux maven(slave). 
it should work right?! specifically i have specified in slave tools also.
let me try with if statement also

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe tried but same error message i'm getting. any other alternative?

Comment: Version 2.13.1 of the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin will be released soon and will include a fix for this issue.